# Return the last word from a sentence

Tags: vba, excel

Trying to get I/O as follows:

```
     Col B is input        Col C will get output
 1   ABC DEF JKH              JKH
 2   KJJB ljac Kjb            Kjb
 3   jabcl sjac casc          casc
 . 
 .
```

But I am getting the error on line 11 as "invalid procedure call or argument":

```
    Option Explicit
    Sub seperate()
    Dim strarr() As String
    Dim str As String
    Dim i, j As Integer
    Dim k As Long
    Dim ws As Worksheet

    Set ws = Sheets("Main")
    k = ws.Range("B1048576").End(xlUp).Row

    For i = 1 To k
    str = Cells("i,B").Value 'Error here as Invalid proc call or argument
    strarr() = Split(str)
    j = UBound(strarr())
    Cells("i,C").Value = strarr(j)
    Next i
    End Sub
```

Comment: I'm not sure if it helps you but I think that `Range.Cells` Property (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff196273.aspx) has to be referenced by numerical indexes.

Comment: One more thing: What do you mean by **i** and **B** in `Cells("i,B")`?

Comment: @HaunsTM it means i'th row and B col

Comment: @HaunsTM after doing the following change still getting same error. 'str = Range(.Cells("i,B")).Value'

Comment: "i,C" is not a valid range name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go.

```
Sub Santosh()
    Dim i&, v, w
    v = Worksheets("Main").[b1:index(b:b,match("*",b:b,-1))].Value
    For i = 1 To UBound(v)
        w = Split(v(i, 1), " ")
        v(i, 1) = w(UBound(w))
    Next
    Worksheets("Main").[c1].Resize(UBound(v)) = v
End Sub
```

Comment: Nope Subscript out of range at v(i, 1) = w(UBound(w))

Comment: Then your data are not as represented. The solution works fine here. Please send me your file and I will sort it immediately. My email is: daniel.ferry@gmail.com.

Comment: ok the error was in column B's data one of the cell in between was an empty one really sorry your code ran fine

Comment: Great. Glad to hear it and that I was able to help.

Answer (score 3):

Consider:

```
Option Explicit

Sub separate()
   Dim strarr() As String
   Dim sttr As String
   Dim i As Long, j As Long
   Dim k As Long
   Dim ws As Worksheet

   Set ws = Sheets("Main")
   k = ws.Range("B1048576").End(xlUp).Row

   For i = 1 To k
      sttr = Cells(i, "B").Text
      strarr = Split(sttr)
      j = UBound(strarr)
      Cells(i, "C").Value = strarr(j)
   Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you this was the perfect solution :)

Answer (score 0):

*str = Cells("i,B").Value 'Error here as Invalid proc call or argument*

Wrong syntax. Should be `Range("B" & i)` or `Cells (i, "B")`